# My Loan amount Field cannot be edited

Tags: custom-object, validation-rule

I have one task in that if my `Loan_Status__c = Fundraising'`, `Loan_Status__c = 'Fully Funded'` then my `Loan_amount_in_rs__c` cannot be Edited only Admin can Edited by using Validation rule how I can achieve this.

This is the validation rule that I have so far, but I am getting an error message when I try to save it

```
AND(
    NOT(ISPICKVAL( Loan_Status__c , 'Fundraising')),
    ISPICKVAL( Loan_Status__c , 'Fully Funded')
), 
TEXT( Loan_amount_in_rs__c )="cancelled"
)
)
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts at this? If so, can you include the attempts you have made and also the issue you face from those?

Comment: Validation rules can't update fields.

Comment: AND(NOT( ISPICKVAL( Loan_Status__c , 'Fundraising')),ISPICKVAL( Loan_Status__c , 'Fully Funded') ), TEXT( Loan_amount_in_rs__c )="cancelled"))

Comment: but  am getting error message its not working for me

Comment: @Andrews You can [edit] your question to include additional details that people ask for in comments. It's generally better to edit your question instead of adding code, workflow, or validation to comments because we're only allowed to do a small amount of formatting in comments (so things become hard to read, very quickly). I've done this for you this time. Also, if you're getting an error message and want help in resolving it, it helps if you  copy/paste the entire error message **verbatim**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to solve the problem using below validation rule code snippet. Assuming **Loan_Status__c** is a picklist field.

```
AND( 
    $Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator',
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(Loan_Status__c ,"Fundraising"),
        ISPICKVAL(Loan_Status__c,"Fully Funded")
    ),
    PRIORVALUE(Loan_amount_in_rs__c) !=  Loan_amount_in_rs__c
)
```